# How Do i make this a grey scale?

Tags: python, pygame

```
color =(random.randint(180,200),random.randint(0,0),random.randint(200,255))
pygame.draw.circle(window, color, (x_offset, y_offset), 50)
```

I tried (0,0) for the color. But it didn't work. i also tried adding random numbers would you need to remove the random color part?

Answer (score 1):

The color is an RGB value. If all 3 color channels are equal, the color is a grayscale color:

```py
gray = random.randint(180,200)
gray_color = (gray, gray, gray)
pygame.draw.circle(window, gray_color, (x_offset, y_offset), 50)
```

or

```py
gray_color = [random.randint(180,200)] * 3
pygame.draw.circle(window, gray_color, (x_offset, y_offset), 50)
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the three RGB values are equal and dark (less than, say 150) it would return a greyish colour.

Code:

```py
dark = random.randint(40,150)
grey_clr = [dark, dark, dark]
pygame.draw.circle(window, grey_clr, (x_offset, y_offset), 50)
```